# how to link a button to a page using jquery provided that onclick triggers some other function too

Tags: jquery, html

I want that the showAll button click should open another page and the showAll function gets executed there so that the results are printed on the new page.Secondly how can i modify the console.log statement to some other so that it prints the result on this(new)page and not on console.

HTML

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li id="add" ><p>Add</p></li>
    <li id="show"><p>Show</p></li>
    <li id="showAll"><p>Show All</p></li>

</ul>
```

JS file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   function showAll()
    {
        var objectStore = db.transaction(storeName).objectStore(storeName);

        objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event)
        {
            var cursor = event.target.result;
            if (cursor) 
            {
            console.log(" Post: " + cursor.value.post);
                cursor.continue();
            }
            else
            {
                alert("No more entries!");
            }
        };

    }


          $("#showAll").click(function()
      {

            console.log("eventlistner called for showAll...");

            showAll();

      });

});
```

Comment: To clarify, are you asking that when someone clicks the 'Show All' list item, it opens a new window(tab?) and executes the ShowAll() function inside that window?

Comment: yes absolutely right..tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be more specific what you mean by `"the new page"`. To pass data between two different pages, you can either:

- Make a POST/GET request, along with the data
- Store the data in a session variable, by a AJAX-call to some back-end script
- Store it in a temporarily cookie
- Use HTML5 with the LocalStorage API

Comment: by new page i meant a new window where the function showAll gets executed. As of now i am  using IndexedDB, how to do it with that

Answer (score 0):

I will make the following assumptions:

- You have a page set up which is seperate to the original page. This page will be called Popup.html
- Your original page does **not** contain the LoadAll() function
- The ShowAll() code is independently executable

Add the following code to the `popup.html` file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var objectStore = db.transaction(storeName).objectStore(storeName);

    objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event)
    {
        var cursor = event.target.result;
        if (cursor) 
        {
        console.log(" Post: " + cursor.value.post);
            cursor.continue();
        }
        else
        {
            alert("No more entries!");
        }
    };

}
```

now on your original page, put the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#showAll").click(function()
{
    window.open("popup.html");
};
});
```

Comment: sorry to say...that the function showAll() is not independently executable. It is a part of code that executes on loading of main html file. How to resolve that.

Comment: If it runs on loading the main HTML file, why is it running on click? It has no parameters, so i assumed it was able to be executed independently... Provide the context?

Comment: the thing is that i am using a database and it has certain variables for db structure which other functions use. Though on clicking the second page opens but it seems that the function does not gets executed at all since it has no knowledge of those variables. I basically want that the result of console.log(..)should get printed on popup.html file in row by row fashion not on the console. So i think it is a kind of passing data from one page to another page.Plz help..